# spring data nullable parameter in specification

Tags: java, spring, null, parameter-passing

I created this specification That return a string and it works well:

```
public static Specification<Eleve> nomIsLike(final String nom) {

        return new Specification<Eleve>() {
            @Override
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Eleve> personRoot, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
                String likePattern = getLikePattern(nom);
                return cb.like(cb.lower(personRoot.<String>get(Eleve_.nom)), likePattern);
            }

            private String getLikePattern(final String nom) {
                StringBuilder pattern = new StringBuilder();
                pattern.append(nom.toLowerCase());
                pattern.append("%");
                return pattern.toString();
            }
        };
    }
```

My problem is that if the parameter is null, the specification does not work and gives an exception which is normal, I want to know how i can make my specification accept a null parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a check for null, and either thrown an exception, or implement null object pattern - ie replace the null with a string, something like : "No parameter supplied".

Alternatively, don't use strings to build a query, and just use the criteria api.

Comment: I think there is an other method without using a condition

Comment: haha, I just hear that and I was asking to know if it's true or not, I'll check and I'll post it if it's true :p